# How do I save kubectl logs to a file on my host machine?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I can see the logs for a particular pod by running 'kubectl logs podName'. I have also seen that logs contains an option --log-dir flag, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there some kind of configuration I can change, logs will be saved to a particular file on my host machine?

Answer (score 45):

```
kubectl logs pod_name > app.log
```

for example, if you have a **kube** pod named `app-6b8bdd458b-kskjh` and you intend to save the **logs** from this pod to a file name `app.log` then the command should be

```
kubectl logs app-6b8bdd458b-kskjh > app.log
```

Comment: This might not work for long running processes with verbose logs, especially on GKE where logs are flushed regularly. So I would recommend launching `kubectl log -f <podname> > pod.log` right after pod startup instead.

Comment: you can also use selectors for easy access. 
eg. kubectl logs -l app=<your-label>

Answer (score 4):

> Note: This may not be an direct answer of how to make the logs go to the host machine, but it does provide a way to get logs onto the machine. This may not be the best answer, but it's what I know so I'm sharing. Please answer if you have a more direct solution.

You can do this using [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/). [Here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/logging/)'s a tutorial about how to set it up. You can configure it to write to a file in a mounted hostdir or have it write to S3. It also allows you to aggregate all your logs from all your containers which may or may not be useful. Combined with [ElasticSearch and Kibana](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/free-alternative-to-splunk-by-fluentd) you can put together a pretty strong logging stack. It will depend on your use-case of course though.

Comment: I am investigating this now. The Kubernetes logs are really pushing for Google Cloud logging or ElasticSearch/Kibana, but my ultimate goal is to develop my own logging stack after I figure out how to get the logs on my local machine first. Thank you for answering. I'll be sure to report back once I've played with fluentd

Answer (score 0):

[Grafana Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/) allows to collect, store and access pods logs in a developer-friendly way.